# new object returns as empty object in expressjs post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

This problem is driving me crazy.

The purpose of this route is to create or login users, I have created new user successfully but I am having trouble sending objects as a response but all it comes is empty object.

I tried `console.log()` a new error that i intentionally created but it does not show up in console either

Here is the app setup

```
// middleware setup
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', usersRoute);
```

my code is like this its not the full code but it shows a place where the code fails

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {

const enteredUser = req.body;

// Validate entered user information
const { error } = validateUser(enteredUser);
if (error) return res.status(400).send(error);

try {

    // Make sure user does not exist
    const isAlreadyUser = await User.findOne({ 
        username: enteredUser.username
    });
    if (isAlreadyUser) {
        const err = new Error('already user');
        return res.status(201).send({
            isAlreadyUser,
            err
        });
    }

// Hash the password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(enteredUser.password, salt);

    console.log(salt, hashed);

    // Create new model instance
    const newUser = new User({
        username: enteredUser.username,
        password: hashed,
        isCustomer: enteredUser.isCustomer
    });

    // Save new user to db
    await newUser.save();

    // generate token
    const token = newUser.genToken();

    console.log(token);

    // send token to front-end
    return res.status(200).send(token);

} catch (error) {

    return res.status(400).send(error);
}
})
```

the response will be like this

```
{
    "isAlreadyUser": {
        "isCustomer": true,
        "_id": "5fb0df0c7f3bb4069ed32615",
        "username": "Raffi2",
        "password": "$2b$10$tlHJGtax75mR4L3gG.cJhuIfy/t7IEKX4n49kIElZ41k7jZAe/2rO",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "err": {}
}
```

the problem happens with couple object types like `Error` and `jsonwebtoke`

can anyone help ?

Comment: What about changing "genToken" to "getToken"?

Comment: "genToken" is a method on the schema that I have created

Comment: Okay, thank you. What is the output of the console.log(token)? Is it defined?

Comment: the thing is the console shows nothing it does not even say defined or undefined

Comment: Okay. Are you sure you are doing a request to this particular route?

Comment: 100 percent as there are no other routes for now this is the only one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224578/discussion-between-wasbeer-and-raffi).

Comment: thanks mate appreciate it, also the other object "token" was undefined as I used this in getToken which is arrow function. reverted to normal function, now issue is completely resolved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `res.status(201).send` call will return an empty object in the property `err` because the properties of the returned object of `new Error('already user')` are not *enumerable* and the response is JSON.stringified.

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44153047/3563737
- [Why does JSON.stringify not serialize non-enumerable properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733878/why-does-json-stringify-not-serialize-non-enumerable-properties)